# KendoGrid filter with datetime picker is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

Here  issue is filter the grid data(service data) based on datetime picker.
 I'm unable to provide the service so i am using here hard code data,but my requriment is filter service data based on date and time.
here is the jsbin   http://jsbin.com/exakic/41/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed the `parse` function in the `grid` definition and not in the `datasource`. You also need to provide a format that matches the one being received ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"). Try this:

```
dataSource: {
    data  : [
        { FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-02-18 19:54:13"},
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-02-18 20:55:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-02-18 21:56:15" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-02-18 22:57:16" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-02-19 20:55:20" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-02-24 20:56:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-02-26 20:57:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-02-28 20:42:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-03-22 11:55:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-03-27 20:55:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-04-18 20:55:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-04-23 20:55:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith", dob: "2013-04-24 20:55:14" }
    ],
    schema: {
        data: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                val.dob = kendo.parseDate(val.dob, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            });
            return data;
        }
    }
```

I would also do a couple of additional changes:

- Include `format` definition in your `DateTimePickers` to match the format in the `Grid`:

Code:

```
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    showSecond: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-MM-yy",
    timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
    format    : "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"
});

$("#datetimepicker1").kendoDateTimePicker({
    showSecond: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-MM-yy",
    timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
    format    : "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"
});
```

- Change `blur` event by `change` event to make it get fired only if the value of the input field actually changes.

Code:

```
$("#datetimepicker, #datetimepicker1").on("change", function () {
    var mindate = $('#datetimepicker').data("kendoDateTimePicker").value();
    var maxdate = $('#datetimepicker1').data("kendoDateTimePicker").value();
    var condition = {
        logic  : "and",
        filters: [
        ]
    };
    if (mindate !== null) {
        condition.filters.push({ field: "dob", operator: "ge", value: mindate });
    }
    if (maxdate !== null) {
        condition.filters.push({ field: "dob", operator: "le", value: maxdate });
    }
    result.dataSource.filter(condition);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply  but when i am using this in service data it's not working properly   var db = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "http://serivcedata",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
},schema: {
data: function (transport) { $.each(transport, function (i, val) {
val.time= kendo.parseDate(val.time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); });
 return transport; },model: { fields: { time: { type: "date" }}} } ,

Comment: Did you use cut & paste for the above text? If so, please review syntax specially open-close curly brackets ({}) and use of ";" in JSON definitions.

Comment: ya  i copied here but in my application syntax is in correct format

Comment: But here is not formatted correctly... How can we do? What about publishing it in JSFiddle / JSBin?

Comment: Does you browser have debugging? Try checking what is it actually posting (if any)? Check also how the page is actually received by the browser (inspect the HTML/JavaScript) in case something gets served incorrectly.

Comment: ya your right but i dont have service with my date format but while using with hard coded it's working fine but not in my aplication means(with service data).here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QSRBR/2778/  i pasted my code here.

Comment: If you cannot show your actual code ... sorry, no more ideas!

Comment: And one more is here date is changing in this format                Mon Feb 18 2013 18:53:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) while using same code in server

Comment: Here is the fiddle with my problem http://jsfiddle.net/mga6f/86/   in this i modified as my application code please check it once

Comment: About formatting the column `dob` you did not specify the format. Define it as: `{field:"dob",title:"dob", format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" }`

Comment: Did you try using a JavaScript debugger? I think it would help you a lot. It says that you cannot invoke `filter` from `undefined` meaning that `result.dataSource` is `undefined`. Since `result` is correctly defined the only option is that `result` does not have a field called `dataSource` and this is because you forgot adding `.data("kendoGrid")`

Comment: ya onabai your right ,i debug the source code here is no error and check it but still it's not giving result. i check the errors in "console". here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/mga6f/90/

Comment: You should use the same format for input fields and for table. Is it an actual requirement have different formats?

Comment: when i am checking in server with service code i am geting the error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'value' of undefined reqkpi.html:740  while enter the datetime in datetimepicker, i am calling "transport" in data function(parse).

Comment: `type="time"`....? I don't think that exist something like that. Check documentation in here http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model#modeldefine

Comment: sorry onabai i paste here old code i changed that as type:"date" than also i am not gettig any result and same error is occuring